# Value returned from mysqli db call in php doesn't return values with newline chara

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok so for some reason when I try and get values from a cell in my table with type TEXT it returns nothing, even thought there is text in the cell. It might be because there are new line characters in the text.  In fact I'm certain that's the reason cause the only time things aren't return from the table is when there are newlines in it.

Here is the code where I get the data from my db:

```
function getRecord($cmo_name,$username,$password){
  $i = 0;

    $servername = "localhost";
    $db = "my_db";

    $return_array[] = "";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); 
    }  

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `Name` = '".$name."'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        foreach($row as $value)
          array_push($return_array, $value);}
    }

    $conn->close();
    return $return_array;
}
```

The above code returns nothing for the TEXT column that includes the newlines.

Help please!!!

Comment: `<input type='text' />`? Where's your code?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Oh yeah, and when the data gets input into the database from the form it's in a textarea input tag.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your query result in PHP's TRIM function to strip the newline and returns out:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: Oh yeah and since there is a null value returned from the query for the text field the trim won't work.